# Multiple Threads Sharing the same function simultaneously

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

if we create for example 3 Threads T1, T2, and T3 that are calling the same function or procedure each of them, then if we call them for an amount of time `T1.start() T2.start() T3.start()` does it work ?? or we need to synchronise them ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not synchronize functions, you synchronize their access to resources.

If any of the functions modifies a common resource <sup>*</sup> while other functions need to access it, either for reading or for writing, you need to synchronize the access to the resource. Otherwise, there is no need to add synchronization.

---

<sup>*</sup> A *resource* could be a member variable, static or non-static, an object in memory, an operating system object such as a file or a socket, a collection, and so on.

Comment: Am having a `Vector` and i was thinking about creating 5 `Threads` that are adding elements to the `Vector` simultaneously, so i guess that my idea is not feasible ??

Comment: @GhassenBellagha Adding to a vector invalidates the collection, so you're right, you cannot do it with a vector without synchronization. If you plan to add elements only at the end of the vector, you could use [`BlockingQueue<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) without additional synchronization.

Comment: So in this case there is no need for `Threads`, i mean i can call normal functions instead of `Threads` because it seems to give the same results !? Even with `BlockingQueue<T>` the `Threads` won't work in parallel so it's the same of working instruction after instruction .. ?

Comment: @GhassenBellagha Of course the threads would work in parallel. Only writing wouldn't go on in parallel, but everything else would. Consider this: you have five threads reading files, constructing objects, and adding them to the queue. Reading files and constructing objects would go on in parallel; adding to the queue would block. Another thread may be reading from the other end of that queue, blocking for the data to become available. It would do its work in parallel with the other threads, too.

Comment: Note that `java.util.Vector` is already synchronized, for several threads writing to the same `Vector`, no additional synchronization is needed.

Comment: @bowmore Right, that's assuming that there's no readers that read concurrently with the writers.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronization is required only if you're reading/writing same variables (state) in different threads. If the methods use only local variables - you don't need to synchronize them.